# Почему не увеличивается длительность исполнения функции?

Tags: settimeout, javascript, замыкания, циклы, функции

```
for (j=1;j<=5;j ++)
{
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, j*500)
    })(j)
}
```

Интересует конкретно данный кусок кода, почему задержка не увеличивается на 500 мс?
Был бы благодарен если кто нибудь описал принцип работы функции.

Comment: почему же?  Очень даже увеличивается. Если не верите, то замените j*500 на просто 500, и увидите, что все пять сообщений в консоль выведутся одновременно, а не через установленные интервалы

Comment: думаю, что автор вопроса ожидает, что сообщения будут выведены через 500, 1500, 3000, 5000, 7500 мс, а у него выходит 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500 мс.

Comment: Хм, у меня в логе:
21:24:46.268 time
21:24:46.834 time
21:24:47.334 time
21:24:47.836 time
21:24:48.331 time
Вообще для таких дел удобно использовать console.timeStamp(), console.time(label), console.timeEnd(label).

Вообще, на идеальную точность браузерных таймеров полагаться не стоит, иногда они ведут себя некорректно. Погрешности можно наблюдать и в данном случае, но "в целом" все работает.

Answer (score 5):

Вы по сути одновременно запускаете пять функций, т.е. ваш код идентичен:

```
(function(i){setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 1*500)})(1)
(function(i){setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 2*500)})(2)
(function(i){setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 3*500)})(3)
(function(i){setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 4*500)})(4)
(function(i){setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 5*500)})(5)
```

Что приводит к эффекту вывода пяти сообщений в консоль с интервалом 500 миллисекунд.

Comment: не знаю почему, но у меня выводятся значения с периодичность в 0,5 секунд

Comment: так и должно быть.

Comment: Вы, видимо, ожидаете что каждый следующий вызов функции происходит только после завершения предыдущего. Это не так. Вы, по сути, одновременно запускаете 5 таймеров:

       500   500    500    500    500
Время:0...500...1000...1500...2000...2500
      |---->console.log(500);
      |---------->console.log(1000);
      |---------------->console.log(1500);
      |------------------------>console.log(2000);
      |------------------------------>console.log(2500);